# returning a triangle

Tags: javascript, for-loop, recursion

I am trying to write a function to return a reverse right triangle but I am having trouble figuring out where I am going wrong.

```js
function triangle(num) {
  let star = ""
  for (let i = num; i >= 1; i--) {
    for (let j = num; j >= 1; j--) {
      star += "*" + "\n"
    }
  }
  return star
}

console.log(triangle(6));
```

My problem is I am having trouble getting the whole function to return a string of * in the form of a reverse triangle. I believe I have concocted the '\n' in the wrong place as well but I am not sure where to change it to.

I am receiving back this:

```
console.log(triangle(6));    
************************************
```

I am supposed to receive back this:

```
console.log(triangle(6));
"******\n*****\n****\n***\n**\n*"
```

I am supposed to concatenate \n to the string output.

-THIS IS WHERE I AM HAVING THE PROBLEM-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```js
function triangle(num) {
  let star = ""
  for (let i = num; i >= 1; i--) {
    for(let j = i; j >= 1; j--) {
       star += "*"
    }
    if(i !== 1) {
      star += "\\n"
    }
  } 
  return star 
}

console.log(triangle(6));
```

See example here: https://codepen.io/bj-rn-nyborg/pen/gOwOdxR

I moved the `+"\n"` to the outer loop, and also initialized `let j = i` instead `num`

Comment: [How do I create a runnable stack snippet?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992)

Comment: Simply post executable js code. 
The code in you example is also a runnable snippet.

Comment: This fixed making it into a triangle but I still need the whole thing inside of a string.

Comment: I have updated the codepen. It now also writes the triangle as a string to the DOM: https://codepen.io/bj-rn-nyborg/pen/gOwOdxR

Comment: I updated my required answer...It is supposed to return "******\n*****\n****\n***\n**\n*"

Comment: \n is a hidden character, it is already in the code i build. That is what causes the new line.
If you want to display it as a string, you will simply need to escape it, you can do it with a backslash, like this: `star += "\\n"`

I have updated the codepen too. 

Comment: This worked..I just had to delete the extra \ and is passed. Thank you very much for your help. The extra bit was what I was really looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`for` statements are used to loop in imperative style, whereas functional style uses recursion. Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means avoiding things like variable reassignment and other side effects.

```js
const line = (n = 0) =>
  n === 0
    ? "\n"
    : "*" + line(n - 1)

const triangle = (n = 0) =>
  n === 0
    ? ""
    : line(n) + triangle(n - 1)

console.log(triangle(6))
```

```
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```